# Creating multiple tables through JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-tables

I am trying to allow a user to press a button and be given three separate tables with different headers. The data for these cells is just “test” in this code.

The problem is that the three tables all join together and make one large table with all of the headers placed side-by-side (see picture at the bottom). How can I make each table occupy its own line instead of creating one big table? The functions for generating the tables is given here, in “tables.js” (note: I know I can create a function to make this document much shorter, but that does not seem to be the issue.)

```js
function createQualtricsTable() {
    var toAdd1 = ["Actions", "Survey Name", "Response ID", "GUID", "Comments", "Submission Date", "WLP", "Current Page"];
    var x = document.createElement("table");
    x.setAttribute("id", "QualtricsTable");
    document.getElementById("app-space").appendChild(x);

    var y = document.createElement("TR");
    y.setAttribute("id", "HeaderRow");
    document.getElementById("QualtricsTable").appendChild(y);

    var z = document.createElement("TR");
    z.setAttribute("id", "DataRow");
    document.getElementById("QualtricsTable").appendChild(z);

    for(i = 0; i < toAdd1.length; i++){
        var newcolumn = document.createElement("TD");
        var t = document.createTextNode("test");
        newcolumn.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("DataRow").appendChild(newcolumn);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < toAdd1.length; i++){
        var newcolumn = document.createElement("TD");
        var t = document.createTextNode(toAdd1[i]);
        newcolumn.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("HeaderRow").appendChild(newcolumn);
    }
    br = document.createElement("br");
    document.getElementById("app-space").appendChild(br);
}

function createODSTable(){
    var toAdd2 = ["AgentID", "HUBID", "Email", "PhoneNumber", "FirstName", "LastName", "SrcSystem", "PartyRoleID", "RoleStatus"];
    var x = document.createElement("table");
    x.setAttribute("id", "ODSTable");
    document.getElementById("app-space").appendChild(x);

    var y = document.createElement("TR");
    y.setAttribute("id", "HeaderRow");
    document.getElementById("ODSTable").appendChild(y);

    var z = document.createElement("TR");
    z.setAttribute("id", "DataRow");
    document.getElementById("ODSTable").appendChild(z);

    for(i = 0; i < toAdd2.length; i++){
        var newcolumn = document.createElement("TD");
        var t = document.createTextNode("test");
        newcolumn.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("DataRow").appendChild(newcolumn);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < toAdd2.length; i++){
        var newcolumn = document.createElement("TD");
        var t = document.createTextNode(toAdd2[i]);
        newcolumn.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("HeaderRow").appendChild(newcolumn);
    }
    br = document.createElement("br");
    document.getElementById("app-space").appendChild(br);
}

function createTealiumTable(){
    var toAdd3 = ["TimeStamp", "Action", "Page Name", "URL", "Details", "Product LOB"];
    var x = document.createElement("table");
    x.setAttribute("id", "TealiumTable");
    document.getElementById("app-space").appendChild(x);

    var y = document.createElement("TR");
    y.setAttribute("id", "HeaderRow");
    document.getElementById("TealiumTable").appendChild(y);

    var z = document.createElement("TR");
    z.setAttribute("id", "DataRow");
    document.getElementById("TealiumTable").appendChild(z);

    for(i = 0; i < toAdd3.length; i++){
        var newcolumn = document.createElement("TD");
        var t = document.createTextNode("test");
        newcolumn.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("DataRow").appendChild(newcolumn);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < toAdd3.length; i++){
        var newcolumn = document.createElement("TD");
        var t = document.createTextNode(toAdd3[i]);
        newcolumn.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("HeaderRow").appendChild(newcolumn);
    }
    br = document.createElement("br");
    document.getElementById("app-space").appendChild(br);
}

function createTables(){
    createQualtricsTable();
    createODSTable();
    createTealiumTable();
}
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
table{
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}
tr:first-child{
    background-color: #4889A7;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td{
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #D0D0D0;
}
```

And the HTML:

```html
<div id = "app-space">
    <form class = "input-form">
        Enter VOC ID
        <input type = "text" name = "vocid" id = "text-box"><br>
    </form>
    <button onclick = "createTables()" class = "button"> Submit </button>
    <script>
        src = "tables.js"
    </script>
</div>
```

[image: tables]

Comment: I think it's working correctly, just having CSS problems because tables... They do look to be separate when I ran the code.

Comment: Dont answer in comments section. edit your question and try to convey the concept as efficient as possible. remove this comment right after

Comment: You might want to revisit the concepts of tables, specifically the role of `tr`'s in table design. You create a single tr and then constantly add columns to it. If you want multiple rows why aren't you adding them?

Comment: @CalebO'Leary do you know how I could edit my CSS to make them appear separate?

Comment: @scrappedcola The idea is to make three separate tables, not three different rows.

Comment: Still stands though. Your not creating 3 separate tables but throwing them all into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that *id's need to be unique!*. In your first function you do this:

```
var y = document.createElement("TR");
y.setAttribute("id", "HeaderRow");
// ...

var z = document.createElement("TR");
z.setAttribute("id", "DataRow");
```

In your second (and third) function you do this:

```
var y = document.createElement("TR");
y.setAttribute("id", "HeaderRow");
// ...

var z = document.createElement("TR");
z.setAttribute("id", "DataRow");
```

So now you have three `TR` elements with the id `HeaderRow`. So what do you think this will do?

```
document.getElementById("HeaderRow").appendChild(newcolumn);
```

Which of the three `HeaderRow` elements do you think it will append to? (hint: it's the first one).

Make your rows have unique id's of use a class and a selector to pick the `.HeaderRow` under (for example) `#TealiumTable`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! In hindsight I should probably just create a function that lets me make tables instead of copying all of that code.